# Tensorflow: Importing GraphDef with Placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

How do I replace a placeholder in a GraphDef loaded from a file to connect the imported graph to a dataset provider?

This script borrows heavily from the [`eval_image_classifier.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) script as part of the `slim` API.

First I open a graph

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
```

Then I set up a dataset provider and preprocessing function using the `slim` API

```
  # Select the dataset
  # Create a dataset provider that loads data from the dataset
  # Select the preprocessing function
  ...
  image = image_preprocessing_fn(image, eval_image_size, eval_image_size)

  images, labels = tf.train.batch(
      [image, label],
      batch_size=batch_size,
      num_threads=num_preprocessing_threads,
      capacity=5 * batch_size)
```

Then I import a graph from a GraphDef from a file and load it into the current graph using `import_graph_def`

```
  quantized_graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(path.join(cwd(), quantized_graph_filename), 'rb') as f:
    quantized_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  tf.import_graph_def(quantized_graph_def, input_map={'batch': images}, name='')
```

Then I set up the metrics and call `slim.evaluation.evaluate_once` to process the batches

```
  # Define the metrics:
  names_to_values, names_to_updates = slim.metrics.aggregate_metric_map({
      'Accuracy': slim.metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions, labels),
      'Recall_5': slim.metrics.streaming_recall_at_k(
          logits, labels, 5),
  })

  ...

  slim.evaluation.evaluate_once(
      master=master,
      checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
      logdir=log_dir,
      num_evals=num_batches,
      eval_op=list(names_to_updates.values()))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Caused by op 'batch_1', defined at:
  File "vanilla_vgg.py", line 319, in <module>
    import_quantized_graph_with_imagenet()
  File "vanilla_vgg.py", line 251, in import_quantized_graph_with_imagenet
    tf.import_graph_def(quantized_graph_def, input_map={'batch': images}, name='')
  File "/localtmp/mp3t/venv/doggett/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/localtmp/mp3t/venv/doggett/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 553, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/localtmp/mp3t/venv/doggett/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/localtmp/mp3t/venv/doggett/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'batch_1' with dtype float and shape [100,224,224,3]
         [[Node: batch_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[100,224,224,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

The GraphDef that I am loading has a Placeholder op with the name `batch`, with the same shape and dtype as the tensor `images`. For reference, running `print(images)` returns:

```
Tensor("batch:0", shape=(100, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Note that I have supplied the argument `input_map` to the `import_graph_def` function that should replace the `batch` placeholder with the tensor `images`. I have also tried using `batch:0` and `batch_1` as the key to the `input_map` but neither works.

According to the documentation for `tf.import_graph_def`:

> `input_map`: A dictionary mapping input names (as strings) in graph_def to Tensor objects. The values of the named input tensors in the imported graph will be re-mapped to the respective Tensor values.

As I understand it, the `input_map` argument should connect the two graphs, but that doesn't seem to be working. See related article ["Connecting Two Graphs Together using `import_graph_def`"](https://blog.konpat.me/tf-connecting-two-graphs-together/). I believe that I am doing the same thing as in the article.

Also, `evaluate_once` is a function that runs a batch of images in a single function call, so I cannot simply call `images.eval()` and pass the result to `evaluate_once` because it would only run the first batch. So the two graphs must be connected and able to be run with a single invocation.